# Enable beep in CentOS that installed in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, centos

I installed CentOS 6.4 in VirtualBox, and I want to use beep. I installed *beep-1.3-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm* but it is not working.

Is there any way to enable beep on CentOS that is installed in VirtualBox?

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox does not have a working "virtual" PC speaker.

See also https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/627

Comment: thank you,
We can redirect the beep to speaker ??

Answer (score 0):

Use VMWare instead, as it does (unlike VirtualBox) have a working PC Speaker. I ran my OS which beeped noises on VMWare and it worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/573292)

Comment: @Ctrl-alt-dlt this provides 100% anwser to question. It is impossible to make it work on VirtualBox unless you some how program it to do so. But Oracle hasnt included PC Speaker in VirtualBox so other VirtualMachine i can think of is VMWare , yes it dosent work in Qemu To